# Problema com INSERT usando PDO

Tags: html, mysql, pdo

Tenho esse código abaixo que esta funcionando perfeito, porém gostaria de altera-lo para funcionar em PDO mas estou tendo problema no cadastramento junto ao BD, quando altero para o PDO.

Ele refere-se a erros

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

na linha 143
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e na linha 164

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código em Mysql que esta funcionando é esse abaixo:

```
<?  if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$cel = $_POST['cel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$plano = $_POST['plano'];
$horas = $_POST['horas'];
$prof = $_POST['prof'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$tempo = date("dd/mm/YY His",time());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE '".$data."' AND horas ='".$horas."' AND prof = '".$prof."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1){

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= http://www.rfclinica.com.br/index.php'>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      alert(\"Esta data e hora já esta agendada para esse Profissional!                               Tente com outro Profissional ou outra data e hora!                                                      Obrigado!!!\");</script>";

return die;

}else{

$inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agendar (nome, tel, cel, email, plano, prof, data, horas) VALUES ('$nome', '$tel', '$cel', '$email', '$plano', '$prof', '$data', '$horas')");


if($inserir == ''){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Ocorreu um erro ao Agendar sua Avaliaço!');
          </script>";


}else{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Avaliação Agendada com sucesso!');
          </script>";

}}}?>
```

E a modificação para funcionar com PDO ficou assim:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$cel = $_POST['cel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$plano = $_POST['plano'];
$horas = $_POST['horas'];
$prof = $_POST['prof'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$tempo = date("dd/mm/YY His",time());


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if( $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM agendar WHERE prof = '{$prof}'")->fetchColumn() <=0) {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE '".$data."' AND horas ='".$horas."' AND prof = '".$prof."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1){

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= agenda.php'>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      alert(\"Esta data e hora já esta agendada para esse Profissional!                               Tente com outro Profissional ou outra data e hora!                                                      Obrigado!!!\");</script>";

return die;

}else{

$stmt = $pdo->prepare ('INSERT INTO agendar (nome, tel, cel, email, plano, prof, data, tempo)
                        VALUES (:nome, :tel, :cel, :email, :plano, :prof, :data, :tempo)');

$stmt->execute(array(':nome' => $nome,
                     ':tel' => $tel,
                     ':cel' => $cel,
                     ':email' => $email,
                     ':plano' => $plano,
                     ':prof' => $prof,
                     ':data' => $data,
                     ':tempo' => date("dd/mm/YY His",time())
                     ));

if($inserir == ''){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Ocorreu um erro ao Agendar sua Avaliaço!');
          </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Avaliação Agendada com sucesso!');
          </script>";

}}}}
?>
```

Minha dúvida e se estou fazendo a alteração para PDO corretamente, e gostaria da ajuda dos amigos para descobrir onde estou errando.
Agradeço desde já a atenção dos amigos.
Abraço à todos!

Comment: Repare nesse trecho: `if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1){` A variavel $sql não está defina no momento que o código é executado. Ao usar o `PDO` não podemos contar as colunas com `mysql_num_rows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *update* passe a data no formato `Y-m-d`, pode também passar data atual diretamente pelo banco usando a função [now()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) do mysql.

```
$tempo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Para obter o número de linhas não use `mysql_num_rows` pois nenhuma conexão com as funções mysql_* foi criada por isso recebe o erro:

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

A função/método equivalente à ela no PDO é `[rowCount()][2]` da classe `PDOStatement`, que é a variável `$stmt` do seu código.

Mude:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1){
```

Por:

```
if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1){
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfeito amigo, era isso mesmo agora funcionou certinho, estou inserindo o código com as alterações.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$cel = $_POST['cel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$plano = $_POST['plano'];
$horas = $_POST['horas'];
$prof = $_POST['prof'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$tempo = date("dd/mm/YY His",time());


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if( $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM agendar WHERE prof = '{$prof}'")->fetchColumn() <=0) {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE '".$data."' AND horas ='".$horas."' AND prof = '".$prof."'");
if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= agenda.php'>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      alert(\"Esta data e hora já esta agendada para esse Profissional!                               Tente com outro Profissional ou outra data e hora!                                                      Obrigado!!!\");</script>";

return die;

}else{

$stmt = $pdo->prepare ('INSERT INTO agendar (nome, tel, cel, email, plano, prof, data, horas)
                        VALUES (:nome, :tel, :cel, :email, :plano, :prof, :data, :horas)');

$stmt->execute(array(':nome' => $nome,
                     ':tel' => $tel,
                     ':cel' => $cel,
                     ':email' => $email,
                     ':plano' => $plano,
                     ':prof' => $prof,
                     ':horas' => $horas,
                     ':data' => $data,
                     ':data' => $data,
                     ));

if($stmt == ''){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Ocorreu um erro ao Agendar sua Avaliação!');
          </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Avaliação Agendada com sucesso!');
          </script>";

}}}}
?>
```

Abraço à todos, e obrigadão pela ajuda.

Comment: Murilo, se a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66488/6454) do rray lhe ajudou, marque-a como aceita, clicando na marca  ✓ abaixo da pontuação.

Comment: @qmechanik, como vc fez o sinal de 'certo' ?

Comment: @rray Pego [daqui](http://fsymbols.com/signs/tick/).

Comment: @qmechanik, valeu hehe o simbolo fica bem melhor que o `V`.

Comment: Olá resolvemos a questão do INSERT, porém preciso impedir que seja agendado o mesmo hoario e data com o profissional que já esteja agendado. Estou usando esse código no MYSQL **`$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE '".$data."' AND horas ='".$horas."' AND prof = '".$prof."'");`**, mas não esta adiantando, pois esta repetindo os dados de agendamento.
Alguem tem ideia de como posso impedir a duplicidade de data, hora para o mesmo profissional? Brigadão, e abraço à todos!!!

Comment: É melhor abrir outra pergunta @MuriloCabral, não se usa like para buscar datas.